# how to call a the class from a method within the class in python to redefine a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having some issues redefining an object that I created by using a method within the same class that defines such object. I have written a small python example. Here I'm trying to create an object called dog3 using a method in the class dog that calls itself in order to change its dog3.getDogName. When I print the dog3 name, the call to **init** did not took effect. Does anyone knows how to perform this operation?

I expect to get an output as

woofy
max
bear

but instead of bear I get woofy again.

```
import sys


class Dog():
    def __init__(self, name = 'woofy'):
        self.name = name

    def getDogName(self):
        return self.name

    def newDog(self, new_name):
        return Dog(new_name)


class Animals():
    def __init__(self, *args):

        dog1 = Dog()
        print(dog1.getDogName())

        dog2 = Dog('max')
        print(dog2.getDogName())

        dog3 = dog1
        dog3.newDog('bear')
        print(dog3.getDogName())


def mainApp(args):
    global app 
    app = Animals(args)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainApp(sys.argv)
```

I'm sure an experience python programer would know how to do an operation like this.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Do not use the tags indiscriminately, the pyqt5 tag was not necessary.

Comment: Thank you All for your responses. I think your answers did the trick! I can see now that my error was on the assigment of the variable and not the way I wrote my Dog class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code have defined the method `newDog` to return a new instance of `Dog`.

Your code also have `dog3` being assigned an instance of `Dog`, but when your code called `dog3.newDog(...)` the return value is not assigned to anything. so the new `Dog` instance that got created went nowhere.

You might want to consider doing this instead.

```
    dog3 = dog1.newDog('bear')
    print(dog3.getDogName())
```

Answer (score 1):

## `newDog` is creating a new dog and not modifying the old one

If you want `newDog` to return a new dog, then do this:

```
dog3 = dog1.newDog("bear")
```

or really you should just be doing

```
dog3 = Dog("bear")
```

If you want `newDog` to modify the current `Dog` instance, do this:

```
def renameDog(self, new_name):
    self.name = new_name
```

Don't make instance constructors unless you want to clone certain parameters. It can get confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The method NewDog "return" a new Dog instance, but it will not change what it is, so if u want to change the name of current Dog instance, do this:

```
class Dog():
    def change_name(self, new_name):
        self.name = new_name
```

if u want to get another Dog instance, do this:

```
class Dog(object):
  @staticmethod
  def new_dog(new_name):
      return Dog(new_name)
```